# Cannot add new custom account from different app with same authenticator

Tags: android, account, accountmanager, android-account, android-authenticator

I have two apps that both use a same custom account type. Those two apps are completely independent and just share the account. When one of them starts, it checks for existing custom accounts and if no account was found, shows the sign-in page.

So I have created my `AccountAuthenticator` as a library project and reference it in both apps. According to this [tutorial](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/):

> Let’s say you copied your authenticator’s code to 2 of your apps, thus
>   sharing its logic, and altering the sign-in pages design on each app
>   to fit the app it belongs to. In that case, the first installed app’s
>   authenticator will be called for both apps when an auth-token will be
>   requested. If you uninstall the first app, the second app’s
>   authenticator will be called from now on (since it’s the only one
>   now).

When I run one of the apps (no matter which app) and call `addAccount` it shows the sign-in page well. **Then, when I run the second app and call `addAccount` nothing happens and sign-in page is not shown. After uninstalling the first app, the second app works correctly and shows sign-in page. So what is the problem and how can I fix that?**

The implementation of `addAccount`:

```
mAccountManager.addAccount(accountType, authTokenType, null, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                try {
                    Bundle bnd = future.getResult();
                    showMessage("Account was created");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showMessage(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, null);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this the correct answer, but I found that the problem is that the apps have different UIDs. So I use `sharedUserId` in both apps and the problem was solved:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:sharedUserId="test.account"
    android:versionCode="100"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Answer (score 5):

**@Misagh Emamverdi**  Yeah .You missing that permission in your manifest .

### android:sharedUserId

The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared with other applications. By default, Android assigns each application its own unique user ID. However, if this attribute is set to the same value for two or more applications, they will all share the same ID — provided that they are also signed by the same certificate.

Application with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if desired, run in the same process.

So ***android:sharedUserId*** is used to share the processes between two or more applications (Like [Udinic Authenticator](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)).

**SYNTAX**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="string"
      android:sharedUserId="string"
      android:sharedUserLabel="string resource" 
      android:versionCode="integer"
      android:versionName="string"
      android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"] >
. . .
```

Answer (score 3):

Find the well written article [Write your own Android Authenticator](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)

[image]